# orientation auto rotation

Tags: iphone, rotation, simulator, uiinterfaceorientation

i have 2 different views for a single nib. when i rotate the screen on iphone "simulator", the view rotates perfectly fine and the output is the desired one. but when i deploy my project on iphone and go through the same process the view doesnot change on changing the phone orientation ?

in view did appear i have used

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
but still no effect.
i dont know why it is working fine on simulator but not on iphone.
I will be really pleased if u help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound ridiculous but do you have the orientation lock turned on? (Padlock in the status bar).